# Bootstrap-dropdown hides under "mainpage"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Im having problem with displaying bootstrap .dropwdown class. It worked from the beginning but stopped showing after a while. Im using a fixed container as "mainpage" throughout the website. Looks like this now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMFgQ.jpg It looks like this when the button is clicked as you can see on the small arrow showing up.

I've confirmed that the dropdown is working and there is nothing wrong with the .js file. 
Here is the body and header im using:

```
<body>
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <span class="brand">doost</span>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="<?php echo $logout; ?>">Logout</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">browse <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="<?php echo $random; ?>">random</a></li>
           </ul>
          </li>
         </ul>
     </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
```

I've tried resetting/removing everything that could have caused this problem without being able to fix it. That includes replacing bootstrap.js/bootstrap.css with default ones. The main page consists of a fixed container that begins in the header and ends in the footer and as I said included in every page. I have several nested div tags inside this container making up the website.

I've also tried increasing z-index for .dropdown in bootstrap.css but nothing happened.

Im using default bootstrap.js/bootstrap.css including one homecook.js/homecook.css

Tell me if I need to provide anything else for you to be able to help me. Thank you.

Comment: You can use jsFiddle to provide us css, js and html bundle, so we can see what's wrong and edit it

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/5xm37/

Comment: Check out `overflow` attributes around the code. http://jsfiddle.net/5xm37/4/. And, please, use left colum to add resources to filddles, do not paste them.

Comment: Okay sorry about the copy paste. First time using jsfiddle. Thanks for telling me. I think I located the problem. Its at line 2985 in bootstrap.css. An overflow property that I changed from hidden to visible. The dropdown menu showed up after I deleted all the cookies and cache in the browser. But then stopped showing at a certain page. Can the .collapse class be altered in some way to override whatever is making the menu hide?

Comment: Okay I found the problem. It was a HTML specific commented-out section that included PHP code that was not effected by it. I took it away and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve this by putting a positive z-index value on the div with the `nav-collapse collapse` classes. In my case, any value greater than `0` did the trick!

Comment: For the reasons behind this, check out [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. 
But when I try your code there was no problem. Did you included all necessary plugin like **bootstrap-dropdown.js**?

Comment: No it bugged on me because I had some php code nested inside HTML that as had commented out. But that did not apply to the PHP code, so I guess it somehow bugged the dropdown functionality. I removed it and the dropdown menu worked again.